# Fatal error: Class 'Category' not found after PHP version upgrade

Tags: codeigniter, phpactiverecord

I use CodeIgniter 2.1 and my production server was updated to PHP 5.4.3-1, and the pages that uses phpactiverecord don´t show nothing and don't show any error.

In my test servers with 5.3.6 works fine.

I use the nightly build version of May 2012. I try with the older versions and stable version.

Php-activerecord don´t work fine with php 5.4.3?

---

**EDIT**: I found that my new server doesn´t have `displays_errors = ON`. After activate it, I see the error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Category' not found in /srv/www/framework/application/controllers/categories.php on line 26
```

at line 26:

```
$data["categories"] = Category::findby($parent_id);
```

categories.php exists in `/srv/www/framework/application/controllers/` and this works fine on PHP 5.3.6.

I need to call something more or call at a different way?

Comment: Is that line in a file with a namespace? Is the class defined in a file with a namespace?

Comment: Sounds like a problem with your autoloader. I don't know how this works in CodeIgniter, but it will be debuggable PHP. I'd start off by setting up a new virtual server with 5.4.x on it, and replicating the problem locally. Also, check the CI mailing list in case it is a known problem.

Comment: Also, is `Category` a model class?

Comment: (One way of solving it quickly is to do a `require_once` on the fully-qualified path of `Category` in `categories.php`. However this is hacky, and not a solution you should be satisfied with. But it will probably get you running).

Comment: @Nanne -- there isn´t any namespace in my code and the class isn´t defined in a file with a namespace. I didn´t work never with namespaces. how I do it? I´m ra

Comment: @halfer -- Category is a model class, and I call her methods on Line 26

Comment: Right coolio. Someone might come up with other ideas, but meanwhile: try debugging your autoloader, or replicate the issue locally.

Comment: I paste my code: Controller categories [link](http://pastebin.com/sjV6mWyR) Model Category [link](http://pastebin.com/YTibkqvn)

Comment: Category extends of PHPactiverecord Class. PHPactiveclass are under a namespace (ActiveRecord). It could be this the problem @Nanne? I must call with a different way or is a problem with namespaces?

Comment: If Category is a Model from phpactiverecord, it could just be your autoloader doesn't work, or it could indeed be the namespace, but then the difference between the 2 php versions is strange...

Comment: I use this [link](http://matthewmachuga.com/post/4571278653/revised-php-activerecord-codeigniter-2-0-reactor) for connect phpactiverecord with codeigniter. Any idea?

Comment: I try to use SPARKS to load Php-activerecord and the behaviour is the same..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

This solution is for php-activerecord through the latest SPARKS version.

Debugging the autoload_function, I´ve seen that the model file was loaded with the first letter capitalized, only in PHP 5.4.3, not in 5.3.x, and the file wash´t loaded.

Find the ActiveRecord.php at

```
yourfolder/sparks/php-activerecord/0.0.0.2/vendor/php-activerecord
```

Search the function:

```
activerecord_autoload($class_name)
```

Line 49 change:

```
    $file = $root.DS.$file_name;
```

for

```
    $file = $root.DS.strtolower($file_name);
```

And now it works!

p.d. I have found another strange case with PHP 5.4.3 before solve this. The function parse_url() returns false if your database password has a '/' on the string. Because of this,  php-activerecord could not connect to the database in the file yourfolder/sparks/php-activerecord/0.0.0.2/vendor/php-activerecord/lib/connection.php at function: file parse_connection_url().

On PHP 5.3 returns the correct array.